# Converting a String whose bits are setup as consecutive, unsigned, 4-byte integers into an integer array in Java

Tags: java, jedis

I'm retrieving what is essentially an array of unsigned 4-byte integers from `Redis`. However, it is stored in `Redis` as a `String`, so a `String` object is what I'm given when I retrieve it with `Java`.

I need to extract all the numbers from the `String`; ideally, into an array. So what would be an efficient means of converting it to the consecutive, unsigned, 4-byte integer array I know it is?

### Update:

As I said, the numeric values are stored in the `String` as *consecutive, unsigned, 4-byte integers*.

The `String`'s bits look like:
*braces and spaces added for clarity

```
{00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001} {00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000} {00000000
00000000 00000000 10000001}
```

which in this case would be the integers [1,128,129].

What I need to do is, knowing that the `String`'s bits are configured as such, convert the `String` into an array/list of integers.

Comment: How are the bytes encoded into the string? A Java String is a sequence of UTF-16 code points and the values of those code points depend greatly on the encoding.

Comment: UTF-16 *is* the encoding.

Comment: How exactly are the numeric values stored in the string? Certain combinations of values are not legal UTF-16 encodings, so it could be that you have garbage there. In any event, you cannot solve the problem without a precise statement of the conditions, which you have yet to provide.

Comment: @DanielPryden updated

Comment: @LewBloch check the update

Comment: The answer to this is simply `java.util.Scanner'` surely?

Comment: Unclear. Why in hell use a String to represent binary data? How did you do to determine that the bits stored in the String are these? I.e. how did you transform the String into bytes to be able to produce that binary output?

Comment: What JB Nizet said. This is a recipe for disaster, IMO.

Comment: So you've basically got a DataInputStream, capture the String as an InputStream, wrap in a DataInputStream, and read the values. Note that you'll have a signed/unsigned issue to deal with reading integers, but that's easy enough.

Comment: @JBNizet It's the most efficient way to store and  increment an array of counters with `Redis`. I know the bits stored in the `String` are these because I'm the one who put them there -- using offsets. I didn't transform the `String` into bytes to get the above binary. That was just an example I typed from scratch to convey to @Lew Bloch how the numeric values would be stored in the `String`

Comment: Then explain how you transformed an array of ints into a String.

Comment: @JBNizet I didn't transform an array of counters into a `String`. I need to do the opposite. I don't know how `Redis` implemented the ability to manipulate the individual bits in a `String`. But they offer the built-in capability to essentially transform a `String` into an array of n-bit counters. In my case they're 4-byte counters. I don't tell `Redis` how many counters I want. I don't even tell `Redis` I want counters. I just specify an offset where each counter begins -- 32 bits * <n-th counter> -- and `Redis` offers the built-in capability of incrementing an integer at that offset.

Comment: I don't know anything about redis or jedis, but I think your question should then be: here's how I created and incremented counters using jedis. I would like to get the values of these counters. How should I do? I'm pretty sure getting it as a String is not the appropriate solution. See https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/AdvancedUsage#a-note-about-string-and-binary---what-is-native which explains what is a redis string, how it is different from a Java String, and says: "In short: if you have binary data, don't encode it into String, but use the binary versions."

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't think this solution is ideal either, but if you've got a better one, I'd love for you to provide it to my [question over at Stack Overflow Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34175/efficient-data-store-for-storing-and-retrieving-mapinteger-integer-data-struct)

Comment: @JBNizet I didn't create or increment counters using `Jedis` they haven't provided support for this `Redis` functionality yet. I was simply asking if I were to retrieve the `String`, how would the conversion be done on `Java`'s side. But I didn't realize there was a difference between `Redis` and `Java` strings, or that I didn't necessarily have to get `String`'s from `Redis` with `Jedis`. That link helps a lot. Thank you